# AndEngine Background Music error

Tags: android, background, andengine, playback

I'm practicing in AndEngine.
I made a background, a sprite, and have added motion and gravity.

So I decided to practice a bit with the background music and sounds, but I have a problem. Now when I start the application I get the black screen, and the sprite is distorted, and of course the music does not sound.

Can you help? this is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
    Scene scene;
    private Music music;
    protected static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 850;
    protected static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    BitmapTextureAtlas playerTexture;
    ITextureRegion playerTexureRegion;
    PhysicsWorld physicsWorld;



    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Camera mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true,
                ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), mCamera);
        return options;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(
            OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         loadGfx();
         loadSounds();

        // resource
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
    }
    private void loadSounds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            music = MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset(mEngine.getMusicManager(), this,"mfx/oldf.ogg");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void loadGfx() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
        // width and height power of 2^x
        playerTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 64, 64);
        playerTexureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createFromAsset(playerTexture, this, "player.png", 0, 0);
        playerTexture.load();

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
            throws Exception {
        this.scene = new Scene();
        this.scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));
        this.music.play();
        physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);
        this.scene.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);
        createWalls();

        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.scene);

    }

    private void createWalls() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FixtureDef WALL_FIX = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 15, CAMERA_WIDTH,
                15, this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        ground.setColor(new Color(15, 50, 0));
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody,
                WALL_FIX);
        this.scene.attachChild(ground);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
            OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Sprite sPlayer = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2,
                playerTexureRegion, this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        sPlayer.setRotation(45.0f);
        final FixtureDef PLAYER_FIX = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(10.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f);
        Body body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(physicsWorld, sPlayer,
                BodyType.DynamicBody, PLAYER_FIX);
        this.scene.attachChild(sPlayer);
        physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sPlayer,
                body, true, false));

        pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
    }
```

Thanks!

---

UPDATE

logcat:

```
10-09 21:07:46.635: E/AndEngine(5305): MainActivity.onCreateGame failed. @(Thread: 'GLThread 4852')
10-09 21:07:46.635: E/AndEngine(5305): java.lang.IllegalStateException: To enable the MusicManager, check the EngineOptions!
10-09 21:07:46.635: E/AndEngine(5305):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine.getMusicManager(Engine.java:294)
10-09 21:07:46.635: E/AndEngine(5305):  at com.example.prueba2.MainActivity.loadmusic(MainActivity.java:73)
10-09 21:07:46.635: E/AndEngine(5305):  at com.example.prueba2.MainActivity.onCreateResources(MainActivity.java:62)
10-09 21:07:46.635: E/AndEngine(5305):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:181)
10-09 21:07:46.635: E/AndEngine(5305):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:110)
10-09 21:07:46.635: E/AndEngine(5305):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:80)
10-09 21:07:46.635: E/AndEngine(5305):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1471)
10-09 21:07:46.635: E/AndEngine(5305):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1241)
```

Comment: Your `mfx` folder is in your assets directory right?

Comment: @kabuto178 yes, is in my assets directory, I think I put in wrong place -loadSounds();

Comment: you got it working now?

Comment: No @kabuto178, I can't make it work, I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Try setting the base path in the loudsounds method like this ` MusicFactory.setAssetBasePath( "mfx/" );` then make the music object like this `music = MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset(mEngine.getMusicManager(), this,"oldf.ogg");`

Comment: I have the same problem, I update whit the logcat error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OOOoooo I know your problem now, add this to your EngineOptions class

```
   options.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true);
   options.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
```

When initiating the `EngineOptions` you must indicate that you will be requiring sound for your scene. Just a slight oversight you made on the `EngineOptions` method.

Comment: you're allright! thankyou!!!, Just, on my case, I use -options.getAudioOptions().setNeedMusic(true);